# TCP/IP JAVA проблема обмена объектами

Tags: java

Очень нужна помощь по вопросу сериализации и отправки объекта с клиента/сервера на сервер/клиент.

Проблема заключается в том, что по сути клиент и сервер - это два разных приложения, самостоятельных пакета. Для сериализации объекта нужно чтобы отправляемый и принимаемый объекты были одного типа.

Вообще не могу отправить на клиент объект `ResultSet rs`. Клиент пишет "String не может быть преобразован в 'Имя моего класса'".

Пользуюсь `Object` потоками

Comment: Покажите код и текст ошибки. Что и как вы отправляете и принимаете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации клиент-серверной системы я бы Вам посоветовал использовать бинарный web-протокол [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_(Web_service_protocol)).

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит изобретать свою сериализацию. Возьмите [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial) от гугла.. Там вы в отдельном .proto файле описываете как выглядят данные, что хотите передавать, из них генерируется утилиткой класс. У каждого получившегося класса есть все необходимое - геттеры, билдер, методы для сериализации и так далее.

Вам потребуются методы `toByteArray()` или `writeTo(OutputStream output)` на сервере и на `parseFrom(InputStream input)` на клиенте

А если еще и транспорт не хотите изобретать - возьмите [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) от апача. Там ко всему выше сказанному еще и сам сервер и клиент уже есть. Но с документацией посложней будет.